# Bash Command Not Found for Simple Variable Assignment

Tags: bash, centos, command, variable-assignment

Why does

```
#!/bin/bash

VARIABLE="value"
if [ "$#" = 0 ]; then
  VARIABLE="value"
fi
```

fail with

```
user@hostname $ ./test.sh 
./test.sh: line 5:   VARIABLE=value: command not found
```

on Centos 6.9? The first assignment works but the second doesn't?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce on OSX, both with bash 4.4 and 3.2

Comment: my mistake: this is Centos 6.9 not OSX

Comment: Looks like those are non-breaking spaces, not real/syntactic whitespace. Just deleting the line and retyping it (in a real UNIX text editor, not a mail program / word processor / etc) might be enough.

Comment: retyping worked...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy how could i have checked the characters? it looked totally fine

Comment: Hmm. I don't know offhand which programmer's editors will show non-breaking spaces distinct from "real" ones. Asking how to configure the specific programmer's editor you use to do that might be a good SO question. :)

Comment: ...see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263939/display-replacement-characters-for-no-break-space-in-vim re: how to make non-breaking spaces visible in vim. Similarly, https://superuser.com/questions/1246965/highlight-nbsp-xa0-in-vim

Comment: Running with logging enabled as in `bash -x yourscript` may have made the issue visible as well.

Comment: Also, you can do `od -c < scriptfile` to see the actual characters